# Why does this list return [False, False, 3, True]?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working through an exercise on Kaggle and was tasked with: Return a list with the same length as L, where the value at index i is `True` if L[i] is greater than thresh, and `False` otherwise.

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
LL = L
for nums in L:
    if L[nums] > 2:
        LL[nums] = True
    else:
        LL[nums] = False
print(LL)
```

That is what I came up with but it prints the list `[False, False, 3, True]`. Also, I replaced the variable "thresh" with the number 2 and added a print instead of a return statement since it's not a function. I'm guessing that this result is because when it hits the 3 or the number in index #2 in the list it for some reason skips over it and I cannot seem to figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Your `for` loop is wrong. You are using `nums` as if it were an index in the array; the problem is that the `in` keyword in Python gives you the actual items from the list, which in this case are the numbers themselves. For example:

```
my_list = [5,3,1,6]
for num in my_list:
    print(num)
# prints 5,3,1,6
```

Also, you should create a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) of the original list so that you don't overwrite the original list:

```
LL = L.copy()
```

**Hint:** if based on this, you understand what's wrong, try to implement it correctly before reading the solution below!

---

**Solution:**

The correct way to implement this:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
LL = L.copy() # this creates an actual copy, not just a reference
for i in range(len(L)):
    if L[i] > 2:
        LL[i] = True
    else:
        LL[i] = False
print(LL)
```

Comment: You also need to *actually* copy `L` instead of just doing `LL = L`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica right, thanks! I was thinking about that, it works without the copy but I guess it would also modify the original list.. edited